# Add Icon to Door Hanger Notification of FireFox Extension

Tags: popup, firefox-addon

I have been trying to add an icon to a doorhanger notification in my firefox extension. I have not been able to achieve this however. The following is what I tried...

```js
PopupNotifications.show(gBrowser.selectedBrowser, "sample-popup",  
  message,  
  anchor, /* anchor ID */  
  {  
    label: primaryLabel,  
    accessKey: accessKey,  
    callback: function() {  
      alert("Doing something awesome!");  
    }  
  },  
  null, /* secondary action */  
  {
    popupIconURL: WWWUP_ResourceURLs.icon
  }
);
```

Using the popupIconURL option. The above does not work, neither does it produce an error.

I have been looking at the method mentioned in documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_popup_notifications#Adding_an_icon_to_your_notification

I do not understand where to append the following code to...

```css
.popup-notification-icon[popupid="sample-popup"] {   
  list-style-image: url("chrome://popupnotifications/skin/mozlogo.png");  
}
```

Some guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS code has to apply to the browser window. You probably have an overlay applying to the browser window, in this overlay you add the following line ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Skinning_XUL_Files_by_Hand#Loading_Stylesheets_in_XUL)):

```xml
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://myExtension/skin/browser.css" type="text/css"?>
```

With `chrome://myExtension/skin/browser.css` pointing to a file with the contents like this:

```css
.popup-notification-icon[popupid="sample-popup"] {   
  list-style-image: url("popupIcon.png");  
}
```

This will set `chrome://myExtension/skin/popupIcon.png` as the icon for pop-up notifications with the ID `"sample-popup"`.

If you don't have a browser window overlay you can get the same effect with a [style overlay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_Registration#style) in your `chrome.manifest` file:

```
style chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://myExtension/skin/browser.css
```